# Why is KDE redirecting back to login page after initial load?

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-environment, plasma

I am running a new install of Debian Jessie and just tried to install KDE and when I login choosing plasma as my desktop environment it goes to a plasma splash screen for a few seconds then goes right back to the normal login screen. How can I fix this? Where would you look?

The content of my `.xsession-errors` file is as follows:

```
Xsession: X session started for nathan at Thu Oct 29 00:56:25 MDT 2015
localuser:nathan being added to access control list
Loading stage  "initial" 193
startkde: Starting up...
kdeinit5: preparing to launch 'libkdeinit5_klauncher'
kdeinit5: Launched KLauncher, pid = 950, result = 0
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Connecting to deprecated signal  QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
kdeinit5: opened connection to :1
kdeinit5: preparing to launch 'libkdeinit5_kded5'
kdeinit5: Launched KDED, pid = 952 result = 0
kdeinit5: preparing to launch 'libkdeinit5_kcminit_startup'
kdeinit5: Launched 'kcminit_startup', pid = 953 result = 0
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Recreating ksycoca file ("/home/nathan/.cache  /ksycoca5_en_ABGG1sD7FGwLWpevNW74RXeZhv0=", version 303)
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kdeinit5 path = /usr/bin pid = 952
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kdeinit5
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi   from kdeinit
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi' from wrapper.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi'
kdeinit5: PID 957 terminated.
Menu "applications-kmenuedit.menu" not found.
Saving
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'KDE_MULTIHEAD=false' from launcher.
Initializing  "kcm_input" :  "kcminit_mouse"
kdeinit5: PID 953 terminated.
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kdeinit5 path = /usr/bin pid = 954
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kdeinit5
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi   from kdeinit
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi' from   wrapper.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi'
kdeinit5: Got KWRAPPER 'ksmserver' from wrapper.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch 'libkdeinit5_ksmserver'
kdeinit5: PID 952 terminated.
kdeinit5: PID 960 terminated.
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = kdeinit5 path = /usr/bin pid = 961
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/kdeinit5
KCrash: Attempting to start /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi   from kdeinit
kdeinit5: Got EXEC_NEW '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi' from   wrapper.
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/drkonqi'
kdeinit5: PID 964 terminated.
kdeinit5: PID 961 terminated.
startkde: Shutting down...
kdeinit5: terminate KDE.
klauncher: Exiting on signal 1
startkde: Running shutdown scripts...
startkde: Done.
```

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: How did you install KDE? the usual method is to install the proper 'task' for that, which you can do with `tasksel`. Also, can you add the contents of the file `.xsession-errors` in your home directory to the question?

Comment: So I did install it using tasksel, and there is no .xsession-errors file in my home directory

Comment: I decided to just reinstall Debian and on the initial `tasksel` screen deselected all the other desktops and just selected KDE. Now it will not even go to a login, just a black screen with a static cursor at the top left corner. I used ctrl-alt-f5 to get a shell and tried running `startx` and it showed the plasma splash screen, then went back to the console and this time there was a .xsession-errors file (posted above) @WouterVerhelst

Answer (score 0):

Check if user home directory is proper and have necessary permissions. I have face similar issue while adding new user in Debian.